# Calculate the expected input resistance

Tags: amplifier, transformer

how would i calculate the input resistance of RS resistor ? to achieve 250mV at the V(in), any help would be great .(i don't[image] even know where to start )

Comment: Why don't you just try different values for RS until you get the behavior you want? You have the simulation in LTspice, just run it.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ye i have done it and i got 92k ohms but ,how would i calculate it ?

Comment: If you have the answer why do you need to calculate it?

Comment: The process of computing Rs for 1/2 of Vs is done by verifying the collector-emitter is operating in a linear mode (it is) then the 100k base impedance is reduced a bit by hFE * (RE//CE) at 1 kHz

Answer (score 0):

This is the napkin approach.
 The input impedance looking in to the base at low to mid frequencies is $$Z_{base}=RE(\beta+1) \approx RE(\beta)$$
where \$RE = Re + r'_e\$. 
At room temperature the value of the dynamic emitter resistance (a parameter that is internal to the transistor) is approximately
$$ r'_{e} = {0.025 \over Ie} $$

Your emitter circuit becomes moderately complicated because capacitor CE  has significant reactance at 1 kHz (corner frequency is around 5 kHz).
$$RE=RE1||{{1}\over{s(CE)}} \;+\; r'_e  $$
|| means parallel combination
\$s=j\omega\$

I'll let you do the maths since it's slightly messy with a reactive component in your equation. Don't forget to add in the effects of the base biasing resistors in parallel with \$Z_{base}\$. There is also the Miller effect which will lower the impedance seen at the base, especially at higher frequencies. As Elliot says, easier to use LTSpice than hand calculate, although, SPICE won't give you intuition how the circuit works. You may be surprised.

A side note, that is not a pretty amplifier since emitter degeneration is pretty much determined by \$r'_e\$ and capacitor CE. It is more customary to have a resistor in series with capacitor CE. This will lower the gain and provide better gain stability over temperature since \$r'_e\$ is temperature dependent. It's also a good idea to do an .AC analysis to get a feel of the gain characteristics over frequency.

Comment: Yes the significant reactance of CE means it has very little (~10%) effect on the input impedance at 1kHz and the value of Rs, compared in parallel with R1||R2 = (100k )|| hFE RE